# unnaming tibbles with `unname` or `names<-()`

Tags: r, tibble

Why is removing names of a tibble via `unname` or `names<-()` not allowed?

```r
mtcars |> unname()
Mazda RX4         21.0 6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46 0 1 4 4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0 6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02 0 1 4 4
Datsun 710        22.8 4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61 1 1 4 1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4 6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44 1 0 3 1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7 8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02 0 0 3 2
Valiant           18.1 6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22 1 0 3 1
Duster 360        14.3 8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84 0 0 3 4
Merc 240D         24.4 4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00 1 0 4 2
Merc 230          22.8 4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90 1 0 4 2
 [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 23 rows ]
 
mtcars |> tibble::as_tibble() |> unname()
Error: ! Columns 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 more must be named.
Use .name_repair to specify repair.
Caused by error in `repaired_names()`:
! Names can`'`t be empty.
✖ Empty names found at locations 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

mtcars = tibble::as_tibble(mtcars)
names(mtcars) = NULL
mtcars
Error in names[old] <- names(x)[j[old]] : replacement has length zero
```

A possible use case for **unnaming tibbles** would be the following, but since [`rbind` does not work with unnamed data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599197/rbind-data-frames-without-names), the example is immaterial.

```r
dir(pattern="[.]xlsx$",full.names=TRUE) |> 
lapply(readxl::read_excel) |> 
lapply(unname) |> 
do.call(rbind, args=_)
```

---

session info:

```r
R.version.string
[1] "R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)"
packageVersion('tibble')
[1] ‘3.1.8’
packageVersion('pillar')
[1] ‘1.8.1’
```

Comment: Please check your tibble version.  I don't have any error using `packageVersion('tibble')
[1] ‘3.1.8’` i.e. 
`mtcars |> tibble::as_tibble() |> unname()
# A tibble: 32 × 11
      ``    ``    ``    ``    ``    ``    ``    ``    ``    ``    ```

Comment: I can reproduce the issue using `tibble 3.1.8` on `R 4.2.2`.

Comment: I had R 4.2.0, butnow I updated to R 4.2.2 and it still works fine

Comment: I can reproduce the error and I think it's not the {tibble} package, but the way it's printing (which is powered by the {pillars} package). I'm on {pillars} 1.8.1. After renaming the `tibble()` the error only arises when printing. Use `str()` and you will see that the unnamed tibble is all there.

Comment: "R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)" and tibble  ‘3.1.8’.

Comment: @Eyayaw I think we need to know your version of the pillar package.

Comment: @TimTeaFan it's 1.8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Works like a charm. What versions are you using?

OS: ***nix**

- **R** version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
- **dplyr** "1.0.9"
- **tibble** "3.1.8"
- **pillar** "1.8.0"

```
tibble(mtcars) %>% unname()
# A tibble: 32 × 11
      ``    ``    ``    ``    ``    ``    ``    ``    ``    ``    ``
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
 6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
 8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# … with 22 more rows
```

Also works on:

OS: **macOS** (intel)

- **R** version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10) / **R** version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
- **dplyr** "1.0.7" / "1.0.10"
- **tibble** "3.1.6" / "3.1.8"
- **pillar** "1.6.4" / "1.8.1"

Comment: What’s your version of the pillar package?